# drupal: adding simple links to a block

Tags: drupal

im using Views to output a block, containing latest post titles - simple and working. id now like to add some text links that should be different than the "more" link you can add through the Views UI. they are basically just p-tags with a-tags inside, pointing to a url of my choice.

right now i just inserted the markup in Basic Information > Footer > Full HTML.

is this the standard way of achieving what im after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write custom templates for each row in a view if you want. Have a look at [views 2 theming](http://drupal.org/node/352970)

Answer (score 1):

Theming is a good way to do it but then it adds an additional responsibility to move the theme file when you move the view from one site to the other.

The header and footer are provided so that you can add html and php code to it, so it is definitely the right way to do it or else it would not have been provided in the first place by the module developer.

Also if the urls are related to the drupal site then I would suggest you to use php mode and add the link using **l** function (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/l/6)